# Запустить скрипт при установке нового сетевого соединения

Tags: windows, vpn, планировщик-задач

Ситуация:
Из-за неправильной настройки корпоративного VPN-сервера в момент установки связи компьютер получает помимо IP-адреса ещё и адрес DNS-сервера, который не работает.
По какой-то причине Windows считает этот DNS-сервер приоритетным и. в первую очередь отправляет запрос сначала на него. Вновь открываемые сайты грузятся очень медленно (пока DNS-запрос не обработается нормальным DNS-сервером).

Временное решение - запуск команды на удаление DNS-серверов у конкретного соединения:
netsh interface ip delete dns "Ethernet 2" all
где
"Ethernet 2" - имя VPN-интерфейса (не меняется после перезагрузки ОС)

А теперь суть вопроса:
Возникла мысль - использовать функционал планировщика заданий Windows, отлавливая событие поднятия нового интерфейса.
Но в журналах Windows нет записей, хоть как-то коррелирующих с данным событием...

1. ОС: Windows 10 Домашняя для одного языка
2. Повлиять на админов не представляется возможным

Comment: Ну а не проще написать cmd-шку, где первая строка запускает подключение к впн, а вторая - удаляет днс?

Comment: Ну если службы, ответственные за обеспечение ИТ-инфраструктуры, не сотрудничают с Вами, отсюда вытекают как минимум, два вывода: 1. Вам не так нужно это VPN-соединение для выполнения рабочих обязанностей. 2. Или Вы не являетесь легитимным пользователем VPN-сервера. Если по существу вопроса, то из утверждения об отсутствии событий в соответствующих журналах Windows следует, что используется специфичное ПО (не из состава ОС). Укажите, пожалуйста, его название в вопросе.